# Is the ModuleNode always the top node in a Twig Node hiearchy?

Tags: twig, twig-extension

I am writing a Twig node visitor and I think it is not reset between files and so I am wondering how could I easily detect when a new file is started.

It seems `ModuleNode` is always the first node for a parsed template, is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is correct https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/internals.html#the-parser says so:

> The parser converts the token stream into an AST (Abstract Syntax Tree), or a node tree (an instance of \Twig\Node\ModuleNode).